# How to get item's parent having items id and parents max capacity?

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, tree

So we have a List `0` .. `N`, and `W` ammount of items each parent can hold (same for all items):

Say we had List of 0..12 items. we know that each item can hold up to for example 3 items so thay form a tree like this:

[image: flat list => tree with cap == 3]

Or say 4 items:

[image: flat list => tree with cap == 4]

We want having item's number in the List get its parent number (item that holds it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parent id = floor((id - 1) / w)